# Add a subform inside Calendar new event form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, form, sharepoint-calendar

So I am making a SP app that should manage Classes, Students, and Sessions (instances of Classes). On the Calendar, I should be able to schedule a session of a class and add the students to the session and track their attendance.

So far I can pick which course the session is through a lookup on the Courses List, and I can add students through a lookup on the Students List (which accepts multiple values). The problem is that I can't track the attendance of each student for the session.

Right now I have something like this:

[image]

But I would much rather this be more like a table where I can edit the attendance of the student as well. I think that the way to do this would be something like making a separate table for attendance/enrollment and then pulling the lookups from there, but the workflows to update this table from the calendar form get complicated really quickly, so I was wondering if there was some kind of way to inject a subform  in the calendar new that could do this for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use multiple worflows.

Create a separate list for storing the attendance.

One workflow which runs on the calendar should create the items in attendance list based on the selected students.

Comment: Can I actually make a workflow that would make one field in the attendance table for each student? I don't really know how I would access each student considering that they are all in one field. Thanks for answering!